# Lattice based cryptography: How do negative coefficients in $Z_q[x]/(X^n+1)$ work?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, lattice-crypto

I saw that in lattice-based cryptography schemes, for example [Dilithium](https://pq-crystals.org/dilithium/data/dilithium-specification-round3-20210208.pdf), coefficients in $Z_q$ are allowed to be negative. For example, in Dilithium the secret key is $s_1 \in R_q^{k \times l}$, where $R_q = Z_q[X]/(X^n+1)$. In the reference implementation and also in the paper, all coefficients for $s$ are in the range $\{-2,\dots,+2\}$, so they explicitly allow negative numbers.

So far I was the impression that $Z_q = \{0, \dots, q-1\}$, but it seems lattice-based cryptography often also allows negative numbers. How does the arithmetic (i.e. addition) work when also negative numbers are allowed? And what terms would I need to look up to read up about the underlying mathematical concepts used when also negative numbers are allowed?

Comment: Thank you very much! Almost: In this other set of representatives, $\{(-q-1/2), \dots, (q-1/2)\}$, what would be the direct formula for addition in $Z_q$?

Comment: Nothing special there. It is the same operation, just convert back to the base representation in the end.

Comment: In other words, "-1" is just a different spelling of "q-1"